# Unable to start a new project, nor close the current one in TestComplete 14

Tags: testcomplete

I'm using TestComplete version 14.0.317.7 x64, on Windows 10

I left my workstation on overnight.  Came back, and Wanted to restart TestComplete, only to find I keep getting the error below when I try to close the program...

[image: Error dialog box]

This error also shows up when I try to start a new Project or Project Suite.  I suppose I can just have Windows kill the application, but I'd rather not do that.  It's pointing to a specific script, but as best as I can tell, nothing is actually running, so I'm confused why such an error message is even there.

Comment: What is the actual error under See details?

Comment: It's the directory and name of a script.  Something like...

ProjectSuite1\TestProject1\Script\name_of_script